# What does an increase in REER signify?

Tags: international-trade, exchange-rates, international-economics

What does an increase in the real effective exchange rate signify? I read from a news report that (localized for India):

> Furthermore, REER is calculated in such a way that an increase in its
>   value signifies appreciation of the rupee. If we assume that the rupee
>   was “fairly" priced in the base year (when the index was set to 100,
>   currently 2004-05), REER of more than 100 indicates that the rupee is
>   overvalued. Since the current value of the trade-weighted REER index
>   is around 115, we see several experts claiming that the rupee is 15%
>   overvalued.

Link to article: https://www.livemint.com/Opinion/6nlCPOcpAw2l0MKUZfv8AN/Is-the-rupee-overvalued-or-undervalued.html

I understand that the REER is calculated using:

- Bilateral real exchange rate with various trading partners
- Weights assigned to these rates according to trade activity

But, I still can't understand what exactly an increase in REER means. If it increases by 10% (say), what exactly does it mean on the ground? And why is it overvalued if it's above 100 -- does that mean a currency is never rightly valued if it's not constant at 100? That'd mean that the REER shouldn't change at all from the base year --- otherwise a currency is **never** rightly valued. How can that happen?